# Catching First Chance Exceptions in Managed Code without being debugged

Tags: c#, clr, debugging

Is there a way to catch First-Chance exceptions, and log them without running under a debugger?

I suppose another way to ask the question is can I write something that will act like a debugger being attached to my process and see what is going wrong while it happens?

Comment: "something that will act like a debugger", perhaps a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on .NET 4.0, you can use the[`AppDomain.FirstChanceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx)event to get notification of exceptions.