# Log caught exceptions from outside the method in which they were caught

Tags: c#, exception, lambda

I have a method like:

```
public TResult DoSomethingWithLogging<TResult>(Func<TResult> someAction)
{
    try
    {
        return someAction.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex)
        throw;
    }
```

This method is used as follows:

```
var result = DoSomethingWithLogging(() => Foo());
```

I also want to log exceptions that were caught inside `Foo()`. I cannot use `throw` in `catch` inside of `Foo`.

How can I catch such exceptions?

Example:

```
public static string Foo()
{
    try
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // I have to log this exception too without adding anything to Foo
        return "Exception caught";            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have these requirements? They seem very specific and effectively cripple the way you can write good code. Perhaps we can find a better solution which suits the actual requirements without having to mutilate code to accommodate it?

Comment: It is in MVC app. It is used in controller as logging of data import from csv file. In case of failed import I should store info about the problem. But now when certain problem occurs I can just skip this line in file. But I still have to log why are certain lines skipped.

Comment: I still think you go about it the wrong way. You could for example expose an event within foo that allows you to react the skipped exceptions. However from the outside assuming anything from the inside of foo is bad design

Comment: You're already familiar with the concept of delegates.  You could pass in a logging delegate.  Inside Foo() you could try-catch and invoke the logging delegate as needed.  However, I don't favour that idea either.  In my comment on @Batavia's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33894167/56793), it seems like you're using exceptions as business logic, a tactic you should avoid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can bind to the `FirstChanceException` event. Here's your code modified to demonstrate this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += 
      (object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}",
          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
      };
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine(DoSomethingWithLogging(() => Foo()));
  }

  public static TResult DoSomethingWithLogging<TResult>(Func<TResult> someAction)
  {
    try
    {
      return someAction.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      throw;
    }
  }

  public static string Foo()
  {
    try
    {
      throw new Exception("This will be caught");
      return"Foo";
    }
    catch (Exception) //I have to log this exception too without adding anything too Foo
    {
      return "Exception caught";      
    }    
  }
}
```

As a rule, I'd be very cautious of this in anything other than debugging scenarios. Once it's caught it shouldn't be considered an exception by code higher up. (Of course, catching it in the first place could have been a logical error, hence this indeed having some value in debugging scenarios).

There are also complications in multi-threaded cases. The code above demonstrates how `FirstChanceException` works, but if you attached before the call and then detached after it would still be triggered by any exceptions on other threads. Filtering those out could be tricky. I'd probably start by considering looking at the call-stack, but I'm not sure that's the best way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by handling the [`AppDomain.FirstChanceException` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Occurs when an exception is thrown in managed code, before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain.

See [Catching First Chance Exceptions in Managed Code without being debugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888670/catching-first-chance-exceptions-in-managed-code-without-being-debugged).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going about it the wrong way. It's a very bad idea to assume anything about the implementation of foo. (Like JDM mentioned in the comments it's a code smell and it WILL get you into trouble)

One way to redesign your approach is to use events

```
class FooClass {

   public event SkippedWorkEventHandler SkippedWork;

   public void Foo() {
      try {
       /* some code */
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         if (SkippedWork != null) {
            /* pass in the relevant data to eventargs */
            SkippedWork(this, EventArgs.Empty)
         }
      }
   }

  public void DoSomethingWithFoo() {
     SkippedWork += new LogSkippedWorkEventHandler 

     try {
        Foo() 
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       /*handle uncaughed exceptions here */
     }

  }
}
```

The reason of this is that from the outside i won't guarantee that i use try/catch to detect what happens within foo. i might rewrite it to a simple if check and return if my test fails. The result of foo with be the same except now your exceptions are not being logged.

With exposing an event you allow anyone from the ouside who is interested in certain things (A skipped line based on your comment) to react on it. and you made a contract saying that you will honor/raise this event.

Comment: Intersting idea, but I'm sure that exception will be caught, because it is an MVC app with filter OnException. And also I don't want to modify the Foo, because Foo must not depend on a wrapper method, it is a method from business logic that is called from MVC controller. And another also: I have dozen of different Foo's

Comment: My point is that you do create a dependency if your rely in FirstChangeException. Namely the dependency from Foo to FirstChangeException. Furthermore, anyone who ever wants to refactor foo for whatever reason will have a VERY hard time figuring out that some code runs while the exception appears to be completely caught & handled

Comment: Furthermore, I would argue that the OP's use of exceptions to manage business logic is a serious code smell.  An exception is something like "the file you tried to read does not exist" or "that string is not an int".  Business logic such as "this line from the CSV contains a value that is not a valid postal code" is a _business error_, not an exception.

Comment: (I would also argue that even my examples of FileNotFoundException and FormatException should be pre-empted by `if (File.Exists(filePath)) {} else {}` and `if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out theNumber)) {} else {}` to avoid using exceptions as business logic.)